# If $Ax = b$ is consistent, how does $b$ get affected by $A$ being a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe the set of vectors $b$, for $Ax = b$ to be consistent in each of the cases
>
> A. $A$ is diagonal non-zero matrix
>
> B. $A = \left[BI\ n\right]$ where $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
>
> C. $A = [In\ 0n]^T$ where $0n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the zero matrix
>
> D. $A = [0n\ In]$ where $0n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the zero matrix

If $A$ is a diagonal non-zero matrix, its already in row reduce form, also since its non-zero there's a non-zero element in last row, which makes this condition completely redundant for describing behaviour of $b$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To improve the writing of your question, consider taking a look at this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome!! What is the meaning of "$Ax=b$ is consistent"? Thank you.

Comment: These were my thoughts. "If A is a diagonal non-zero matrix, its already in row reduce form, also since its non-zero there's a non-zero element in last row, which makes this condition completely redundant for describing behaviour of b." I also posted the original question as a reference

Comment: Ax= b is consistent means the set of equations represented by matrices A(m*n), x(1*m) and b(1*n) are consistent